# R dynamically import library

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function that will either load a library if it exists, or try to install it if it does not. Where I am stuck is how to dynamically use the `library` function. R makes this hard because the `library` function doesn't only accept a string.

For instance, to load h2o:

```
library('h2o') ## This works
library(h2o) ## This also works...
```

But what if I have a variable named `h2o`?

```
h2o <- 'plyr'
library(h2o) ## imports the h2o package, not plyr
```

How can I use a variable to dynamically load a package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `character.only=TRUE` option for your `library` call.  See `?library`:

```
h20 <- "plyr";
library(h20, character.only=TRUE);

sessionInfo();
```